# dependencies compiled using androidTestCompile are not recognized

Tags: android, robotium-recorder

I am trying to integrate robotium-solo 5.5.4 into my project.

If i run this line:

```
compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.5.4'
```

then everything is fine,
however if I run this line:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.5.4'
```

it is like the dependency is not there.

What can I do to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
testCompile
```

instead of

```
androidTestCompile
```